# Symfony 2. Controller's createForm does not bind Model to submodels

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 models, and 2 from types. FormType "EventSchedule" is a subform of "Event".  When i tried to use `$this->createForm(new EventType(), $event);` in my  controller, I got the form but EventSchedules(that are the part of Event) have no links to related events.

```
/**
 * Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Voulidance\SharedBundle\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(max = "50", maxMessage="The value is too long. It should have maximum {{ limit }} characters")
     * @Assert\NotBlank() 
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message = "The date should be in format 'mm/dd/yyyy'.")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Start date field should not be blank.")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message = "The date should be in format 'mm/dd/yyyy'.")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "End date field should not be blank.")
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EventSchedule", mappedBy="event", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"dayOfWeek" = "ASC", "startTime" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $eventSchedules;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventSchedules = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getStartDate() {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function getEndDate() {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    public function getEventSchedules() {
        return $this->eventSchedules;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setStartDate($startDate) {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
    }

    public function setEndDate($endDate) {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
    }

    public function setEventSchedules($eventSchedules) {
        $this->eventSchedules = $eventSchedules;
    }

    public function addEventSchedule(EventSchedule $eventSchedule)
    {
        $this->eventSchedules->add($eventSchedule);
    }

     public function removeEventSchedule(EventSchedule $eventSchedule)
    {
        $this->eventSchedules->removeElement($eventSchedule);
    }




   /**
 * EventSchedule
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Voulidance\SharedBundle\Repository\EventScheduleRepository")
 */
class EventSchedule extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startTime", type="time", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Time()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, fill in all fields.")
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endTime", type="time", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Time()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, fill in all fields.")
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dayOfWeek", type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, fill in all fields.")
     */
    private $dayOfWeek;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="eventSchedules")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, fill in all fields.")
     */
    protected $event;


    //Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, fill in all fields.")

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStartTime() {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    public function getEndTime() {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    public function getDayOfWeek() {
        return $this->dayOfWeek;
    }

    public function getEvent() {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setStartTime($startTime) {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEndTime($endTime) {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDayOfWeek($dayOfWeek) {
        $this->dayOfWeek = $dayOfWeek;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEvent($event) {
        $this->event = $event;
        return $this;
    }

}

    class EventType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('name', null, array(
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array('id'=>"page-name", 'size'=>"24", 'class'=>'auth'),
            'required'=>true
        ))->add('startDate', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => false,
            'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'invalid_message' => "Start date format should be 'mm/dd/yyyy'.",
            'attr' => array('data-date'=>"", 'placeholder'=>"mm/dd/yyyy", 'size'=>"18",'class'=>"auth date holiday-start-date hasDatepicker", 'id'=>"holiday-start-date")
        ))->add('endDate', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => false,
            'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'invalid_message' => "End date format should be 'mm/dd/yyyy'.",
            'attr' => array('data-date'=>"", 'placeholder'=>"mm/dd/yyyy", 'size'=>"18",'class'=>"auth date holiday-start-date hasDatepicker", 'id'=>"holiday-start-date")
        ))->add('eventSchedules', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new EventScheduleType(),
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'error_bubbling'=>false
            ))->add('id', 'hidden');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Voulidance\SharedBundle\Entity\Event',
            'cascade_validation' => false,
            'validation_groups' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'event';
    }
}

    class EventScheduleType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('startTime', 'us_time', array(
            'widget' => 'text',
            'label' => 'From',
            'attr' => array('maxlength' => '2', 'placeholder' => 'hh:mm'),
            'invalid_message' => 'Time value is not valid.',
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ))->add('endTime', 'us_time', array(
            'widget' => 'text',
            'label' => 'To',
            'attr' => array('maxlength' => '2', 'placeholder' => 'hh:mm'),
            'invalid_message' => 'Time value is not valid.',
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ))->add('dayOfWeek', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                1 => 'Everyday',
                2 => 'Sunday',
                3 => 'Monday',
                4 => 'Tuesday',
                5 => 'Wednesday',
                6 => 'Thursday',
                7 => 'Friday',
                8 => 'Saturday',
            ),
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array('size'=>'15'),
            'multiple' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ))->add('id', 'hidden', array('label' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Voulidance\SharedBundle\Entity\EventSchedule',
            'cascade_validation' => false,
            'validation_groups' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'eventSchedule';
    }

}

     /**
     * Save event
     *
     * @Route("/save", name="admin_event_save")
     * @Template("VoulidanceAdminBundle:Event:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function saveAction(Request $request) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $eventRepository = $em->getRepository("VoulidanceSharedBundle:Event");
        $event = new Event();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $event);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $schedules = $form->get('eventSchedules')->getData();
        foreach($schedules as $schedule){
            $schedule->setEvent($event);
        }
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $errors = $this->validateSchedules($schedules);
            if(count($errors) > 0){
                return new JsonResponse(array('subformError'=>true, 'errors'=>$errors));
            }
            $em->persist($event);
            $em->flush();
            return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true, 'events'=>$eventRepository->findAll()));
        }
        return new JsonResponse(array('error' => true, 'errors'=>(string)$form->getErrors(true)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set event to eventSchedule in the addEventSchedule method of event class.

```
public function addEventSchedule(EventSchedule $eventSchedule)
{
    $eventSchedule->addEvent($this);
    $this->eventSchedules->add($eventSchedule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't test the code right now, I think I can see the problem and answer your question so that maybe you can work on it.

```
$schedules = $form->get('eventSchedules')->getData();
```

should be:

```
$schedules = $event-> getEventSchedules();
```

because you need the mapped data which $form->handleRequest($request); is filling into $event object.

Comment: That part of code where i manually set events could be skipped. Symfony validates the form on the step $form->handleRequest($request); So event should be binded to eventSchedules on this step

Comment: $form->get retrieves the data that came from the request... but after the request is handled that data is mapped to and available through the form type you used when creating the form object. What I mean is: $form->get('eventSchedules')->getData(); retrieves the data from the form object while using $event->getEventSchedules(); retrieves the collection from the $event entity after the form mapped the request to objects.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that $eventSchedule->getEvent() == null

Comment: Form already validated with handleRequest() method when i try to set events to eventSchedules. so my changes do nothing.